# PHP save XML's Tag Value to PHP variable

Tags: php, xml, soap-client

Hi after this lines of codes:
`$client = new SoapClient("http://rscnagahrd/OracleWS/Oracle.asmx?WSDL");`
`$result = $client->getFoods();`
`$objResult = simplexml_load_string($result->getFoodsResult->any);`

I want to extract the values from `$objResult`'s Tags to a PHP Variable.

When `I var_dump($objResult);`

I get:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (1) { 
["NewDataSet"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (1) { 
    ["Table"]=> array(4) { 
        [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (4) { 
            ["FOOD_ID"]=> string(1) "1" 
            ["FOOD_NAME"]=> string(6) "Burger" 
            ["FOOD_DESC"]=> string(15) "100% Beef Patty" 
            ["FOOD_PRICE"]=> string(2) "25" 
        } 
        [1]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (4) { 
            ["FOOD_ID"]=> string(1) "2" 
            ["FOOD_NAME"]=> string(4) "Coke" 
            ["FOOD_DESC"]=> string(6) "Drinks" 
            ["FOOD_PRICE"]=> string(2) "10" 
        } 
        [2]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (4) { 
            ["FOOD_ID"]=> string(1) "3" 
            ["FOOD_NAME"]=> string(5) "Pepsi" 
            ["FOOD_DESC"]=> string(6) "Drinks" 
            ["FOOD_PRICE"]=> string(2) "10" 
        } 
        [3]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#9 (4) { 
            ["FOOD_ID"]=> string(1) "4" 
            ["FOOD_NAME"]=> string(12) "French Fries" 
            ["FOOD_DESC"]=> string(16) "Made from France" 
            ["FOOD_PRICE"]=> string(2) "15" 
        } 
    } 
}
```

}

I want to for example store all items with TAG "FOOD_NAME" be assigned to a PHP variable
  `$foodname(0)`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking the same that has been outlined in the PHP manual. See [Basic SimpleXML usage](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$foodname = array();
foreach ($objResult->NewDataSet->Table as $table) {
    $foodname[] = $table->FOOD_NAME;
}

echo $foodname[0]; // first element of the array
```

Comment: Hi, your solution worked but when I echo `$foodname` all the names are displayed, ie. `BurgerCokePepsiFrench Fries`, I tried `$foodname[0]` but it displays only `B` and `$foodname[1]` displays `u`..etc..

Comment: In that case use `array` , answer updated